# How to save and restore window layout in SlickEdit?

Tags: slickedit

When using the [SlickEdit](http://www.slickedit.com/) IDE, is there a way to save and restore the window layout?

Window layout is saved when closing and re-opening the workspace. Multiple workspaces would allow multiple window layouts, even when viewing the same projects. However, multiple workspaces create multiple tag files, which take a long time to rebuild for large projects.

Is there a way to either save and restore window layouts within one workspace, or share the workspace tag file between multiple workspaces?

Answer (score 1):

The window layout (and other info) is maintained in the `*.vpwhist` file.
If you create several different `*.vpwhist` files for you layout needs, and rename the appropriate one you wish to use to `<project>.vpwhist`, you'll probably have what you need.

I didn't try, though.

Answer (score 0):

Save/ restore sessions saves a subset of the information that vrestore.slk has in it but to any file of your choosing.  I don't have a complete list of what gets saved but it includes open buffers, windows (including the new troublesome floating windows :) ) and bookmarks.

See [xsave_session](http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?topic=9389.0)

Answer (score 0):

Create additional workspaces for each layout.

1. Use a different file name for the project and the workspace. e.g. `a-project.vpj` and `workspace1.vpw`.
   (Essential so that the workspace and project tag files never have a name collision, which SlickEdit works around by creating an alternative project tag file name.)
2. Configure project to use a project specific tag file.
   (This avoids duplicating tag data.)

   1. Menu: Project: Project Properties: Files: **Tag files with project-specific tag file**
3. Duplicate the workspace file `example.vpw`, to e.g. `example2.vpw`.
4. Use Project: Open Workspace to then open the new workspace.
5. Projects are then listed as recent projects, easy to switch again.

For each additional workspace the window layout will be saved.

```
workspace1.vpw
     |
     +--> workspace1.vpwhistu (window layout information)
     +--> workspace1.vtg      (tiny tag file)
     `-------------------------.
                               |
workspace2.vpw                 |
     |                         |
     +--> workspace2.vpwhistu  |
     +--> workspace2.vtg       |
     `-------------------------.
                               |
workspace2.vpw                 |
     |                         |
     +--> workspace2.vpwhistu  |
     +--> workspace2.vtg       |
     `-------------------------`--> a-project.vpj
                                         |
                                         `--> a-project.vtg
                                              (large project tag file)
```

Not an ideal solution because:

1. Files must be duplicated outside of SlickEdit, then workspaces added.
2. Switching workspaces causes SlickEdit to reconsider all files for updating the tag file.